# Search and replace files (Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, console, linux-mint

I'm quite new to Linux. I'm using Linux Mint and I've just found a situation where I have a file which exists multiple times inside the tree/folders of a folder. I want to replace all occurrences of this file with a new version of it.
So instead of looking for that file once and again and replacing it with the new one, I wonder if there is any kind of search & replace command for files.

I've already searched for a similar question in stackoverflow, but I was only able to find commands to search & replace TEXT in files, not the file itself.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can always do it in parts, like:

1. Get a list of items matching your search.
2. Replace every match (using mv for example) with your file.

something like:

```
foreach dir ( `ls | egrep '^(i686\|amd64)\.'` )
   mv yourfile $dir
end
```

Comment: Oh... I thought it was simpler. Would this be recursive?